# Baseball Cards (arrays and structs)

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where I have to display the name of the baseball player, year, and batting average for 3 years, up to the year the card was issued. I must use arrays, structures, user defined functions and "for", "and", and/or "while" loops. I tried typing in the arrays according to my textbook but when I try to debug it, it says the string subscript is out of range.

This is what I have so far...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6zI0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSUBU.png)

Comment: Please share your original code here. Do not include your code in images. It's recommended to edit your question and add it.

Comment: For some reason it won't let me edit the question because it said it had errors in the code I provided.

Comment: ***it says the string subscript is out of range.*** Trust that this is a correct diagnosis. The debuger should alos allow you to look at the subscript after it tells you that you have gone out of bounds.

Comment: `cin >> playerName[100];` is a bug. It should be `cin >> playerName;` The playerName variable is empty and does not have 101 characters in it before the call. Also cin >> playerName[100]; is trying to read a single character to the 101th index of the variable.

Comment: @drescherjm true, he's using a string for playerName but using arrays for it. But it seems like there's something wrong in 2nd image's for loop. Assigning the calculation to "playerName"? That's so weird.

Comment: I agree, the second code image looks weird. Why was playerName used in some math calculation?

Comment: @JCVelez my advice is to step back and write smaller programs before attempting something this complicated. You have written too much code without testing and understanding the concepts needed to continue. There are some very strange things in both images. I am not sure if you wanted to create a `struct` to represent a single player or you wanted separate arrays. Also you repeat the same variable names in different scopes. I don't think we can help fix the code.